# Issue with ntdll

Tags: crash, windows, ntdll

I see a crash while trying to run a Windows application.

When I check the Event viewer log, it says - Faulting module name: ntdll

What could be the issue here? I have ntdll in my machine (in the system folder)

I saw it on multiple machines. On one occasion, replacing the existing ntdll with a different one from a machine that worked did the trick.

Wanted to understand what role does ntdll plays in an application..as in what functionalities or Win32 API's will be impacted if ntdll is bad.

Comment: click on the `ntdll` tag :) or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files

Comment: A Windows Application, which application?